# Strange result in JasperSoft with null date column

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am getting this result when I publish a report based in a query from mysql.

[image]

In this query I am selecting a date value called date_out, this column can be null. The problem is that when I hae this column in my select list, in presence of the first null value the rest of the report is show with null for all of the columns involved in all the 179 pages. But when I delete this column from the select, I am getting the expected result. However I do not understand this behavior.

[image]

Want can be happening?

Days in status is just the difference between date_in and date_out

Regards.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe you should post the incident at Jaspersoft bug tracker

Comment: Post your query and JRXML here. So that we can check what is wrong with it.